# Can security vulnerabilities in npm packages be of concern for a ReactJs/Django website?

Tags: django, security, npm

I am developing a website with `React.js` frontend and `Django` backend.
After updating all `npm` packages to their newest versions and performing `npm audit fix`, I still get the following message from `npm audit`:

```
found 14 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 5 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I wonder whether I should be concerned about these vulnerabilities, given that they concern only the frontend? When I wrote the backend, I always assumed that an ill-intending user can substitute the frontend and submit any request whatsoever to the backend.

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802267/importance-of-npm-vulnerabilities-for-build-processes) question is somewhat similar, but its author does not use the `npm` packages with vulnerabilities for any live process, while I use them as part of my frontend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importance of NPM vulnerabilities for build processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802267/importance-of-npm-vulnerabilities-for-build-processes)

Comment: @ErickTOliveira Not really. In contrast to that question, I do use these packages as part of my frontend. I hade added an edit. Thanks!

Comment: Network calls are recorded in the browser’s dev tools so it is possible that your backend can receive requests from another client. That shouldn’t be of concern though if you’ve added proper authentication/permissions to your endpoints.